# Beautifying PL SQL script output

Tags: plsql, report, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote a PL SQL procedure in SQL Developer that outputs the results of a select query. The output appears in 'Script Output' window. The output does not appear in grid form like in a normal SQL query though. I would like the output of the PL SQL to be a report for other parties. Currently, I am copying the output and pasting it into an excel file.

Is there a way to beautify (visually/formatting/file) the script output? I'm thinking about something along the lines of the grid form as with normal query outputs or as the blue HTML tables that is available in the "Reports" section.

Thanks!

Comment: why not spool the output to a csv file so it can be opened in Excel, if that is what you want ?

Comment: I do spool the output. The data is there, but it is not as pleasing to the eyes as I would like. Is there any way to jazz it up? On a semi-related note, the output is missing field headers. How might I add include field headers in the csv file?

Comment: to add headers, only option is to do `dbms_output.put_line('column header1' || ',' || 'column header 2' ... )`

Comment: currently, I already have the output of dbms_output.put_line(table.field1||','||table.field2). The output are just the records in that table. How might I add column names to this?

Comment: Can you post code snippet and current and expected output

Comment: `DECLARE cursor emp_cur is
SELECT date,
    comm
   Cast(CASE
    WHEN Substr(comm, Length(comm), 1) = '-' THEN
       Concat('-', Substr(comm, 0, Length(comm) - 1))
         ELSE Substr(comm, 0, Length(comm))
          END AS FLOAT) / 100
FROM   myname.mytable
BEGIN
for emp_rec in emp_cur
loop
dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.date||','||Cast(CASE
     WHEN Substr(emp_rec.comm, Length(emp_rec.comm), 1) = '-' THEN
              Concat('-', Substr(emp_rec.comm, 0, Length(emp_rec.comm) - 1))
   ELSE Substr(emp_rec.comm, 0, Length(emp_rec.comm))
  END AS FLOAT)/100 );
end loop;
end;`

Comment: current output:
May 16 2017 50050
May 15 2016 800
..
May 1 2016 100

desired output:
**Date**             **Comm**
May 16 2017 50050
May 15 2016 800
..
May 1 2016   100

Comment: when i try to apply the techniques from here, the output is blank https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016 .Theres code prior to the select statement which exports the output to a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, you just need to add some header

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR emp_cur
    IS
        SELECT DATE v_dte,
            CAST(
                CASE
                    WHEN SUBSTR(comm, LENGTH(comm), 1) = '-'
                    THEN Concat('-', SUBSTR(comm, 0, LENGTH(comm) - 1))
                    ELSE SUBSTR(comm, 0, LENGTH(comm))
                END AS FLOAT) / 100 comm
        FROM myname.mytable;
BEGIN
    -- Add the first line of output as the header
    dbms_output.put_line('Date' || ',' || 'Comm');
    FOR emp_rec IN emp_cur
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.v_dte ||',' ||emp_rec.comm);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Also, don't name your table field names as standard data types.